# path name with parameters in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a link

like :

```
www.localhost.com/test/#test1
```

i want this output

```
test/#test1 using jquery
```

here is my code

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// my code which is working fine 
       jQuery(this).attr('href','test/#test1');

        alert(window.location.pathname);

        });
```

Now i am getting this

**test**

Does Anybody have idea about that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
    alert(window.location.pathname + location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test is the path and #test is a anchor and part of the query of the url.